# Convert sound encoded in RTTY 45.45 baud using minimodem

Tags: audio, modem, telephony

I've downloaded a [file encoded in RTTY 45.45 baud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_jMLGpZ1Eo) (mp3 output of linked video). *I'm not sure if the final output should be audio or text.*

I've also installed `minimodem` which I'm reading can convert data into audio with option `--tx` and out with `--rx`.

For example converting a picture into audio and back with:

```
cat pic.jpg | minimodem --tx 9600 -f audio.wave

minimodem --rx 9600 -f audio.wave > pic2.jpg
```

I tried the following two commands, one expecting audio output and another expecting text:

```
minimodem --rx rtty -f youtube.mp3 > out.mp3

minimodem --rx rtty -f youtube.mp3 > out.txt
```

Neither of these seem to work.

Can anyone advise me on how to decode this story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `minimodem`, but found the following eventually worked:

```
minimodem -a --rx rtty --stopbits 1 -f new1ch.wav
```

which produces output like

```
### CARRIER 45.45 @ 740.0 Hz ###
SET YOUR DECODER MODE TO RTTY 45
START TRANSMISSION...
HELLO AND WELCOME TO ANOTHER STRANGE BEACONS RTTY STORY.
```

The command did not seem to like an mp3 file as input, and when I converted that to wave it said *input stream must be 1-channel*, so I used `sox new.mp3 -c1 new1ch.wav` to reduce the file to 1 channel.  The option `-a` made the command auto-detect the carrier frequency of 740hz. Initially, the text output was recognisable but with missing letters, so I tried the `--stopbits 1` to override the default of 1.5 and that helped a lot.